# Interpreting etherereum eth client console logs

Tags: ethereum

I'd like to understand what the eth client throws out (logs) when I call it through the console (see snapshot below). I have been unable to find any definitions that would help me interpret these logs. Any pointers?

[image]

Comment: *Any pointers?* https://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: @Leon Adler: very funny! ;o)

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for those logs.